# Dynamic GUI size

Tags: java, resize, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I have this problem with resizing some JPanels in a GUI application. The application has a main JLayeredPane which contains 2 other JPanels. In JPanel 1 I have a login form and a button. When I press the button I want to make the first JPanel invisible and the second JPanel visible (this panel is bigger than the first), but remains the same size. Bellow is some relevant code. Can anyone help me?

```
int width=300, height=300;
JLayeredPane mainPanel;
JPanel panel1;
JPanel panel2;

panel1.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
panel1.setBackground(new Color(251, 249, 236));
mainPanel.add(panel1, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

panel2.setBounds(0, 0, width+200, height+200);
panel2.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
mainPanel.add(panel2, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
```

And the clicked button code:

```
setSize(width+200, height+200);
    panel1.setVisible(false);
    panel2.setVisible(true);
    mainPanel.setSize(width+200, height+200);
    mainPanel.validate();
    mainPanel.repaint();
```

Here is some code for the JLayredPane:

```
GroupLayout mainLayout=new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(mainLayout);

        mainLayout.setHorizontalGroup(mainLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(mainLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(mainPanel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, width, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        mainLayout.setVerticalGroup(mainLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(mainLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(mainPanel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, height, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
```

LE:

for the button:

```
setSize(width+200, height+200);

        mainPanel.setSize(width+200, height+200);
        mainPanel.remove(panel1);
        mainPanel.remove(panel2);
        mainPanel.add(panel2, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        actualizare();
        mainPanel.validate();
        mainPanel.repaint();
        validate();
        repaint();
```

The function:

```
void actualizare(){
        GroupLayout mainLayout=new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(mainLayout);

        mainLayout.setHorizontalGroup(mainLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(mainLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(mainPanel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, width+200, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );
        mainLayout.setVerticalGroup(mainLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(mainLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(mainPanel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, height+200, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

    }
```

Comment: Why not remove `panel1`, then add `panel2`, and then call `repaint` on `mainPanel`, as Harry Joy suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling validate() and repaint() at the end.

Comment: Validate and repaint should be called to what?

Comment: First try to call repaint() and validate() to frame that is for what you are doing this `setSize(width+200.,height+200)` and then try this: instead of changing visibility flag try to add/remove panel to mainPanel.

Comment: I have edited some code and added the code for the mainPanel.

Comment: @lonut: try this: `setSize(width+200, height+200);
    panel1.setVisible(false);
    panel2.setVisible(true);
    mainPanel.setSize(width+200, height+200);
    mainPanel.validate();
    mainPanel.repaint(); validate();repaint()`

Comment: @Harry: Still nothing. Trying the second method with add/remove.

Comment: @Harry: Tryied the add/remove method... still nothing.

Comment: Done! I have made a function that takes the layout of the main frame and add that layout to the JLayeredPane. I'll post the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).